# Magento : Product URL with full category path

Tags: magento

I have the following magento categories...

```
Category A / Sub Category B
```

Product URL shows only the Sub Category B. But I need the full category path along with the root category, eg:

```
www.mydomain.com/category-a/category-b/product.html
```

Can someone help to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check your settings in System->Config->Catalog->Search Engine Optimization. Magento should have the path you've described from the start.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked the SEO settings. Use Categories Path for Product URLs set to Yes, Is there anything i need to modify. I am trying solve issue for past 2 days

Comment: Is your "Catalog Rewrite URLs" index up-to-date?

Comment: Which controller, which template and which code is used to generate the product URL in question?

Comment: Is there any way to check whether my Catalog Rewrite URLs index is up to date or not. I have re index my Catalog URL Rewrites many times.

Comment: Also i have not written my own coding to do so. By default is coming like this only.

Comment: To see whether an index is up-to-date check the `Last Run` column of your `System -> Index Management` grid.

Comment: There are product URLs in many places in Magento (e.g. in Category Views (Grid/Lists), Bestseller blocks, Compare products blocks, Recently viewed products block, Product wishlists, etc.). So, even if you didn't code s/t yourself, we still need to know, which Magento controller and template exactly you're talking about.

Comment: Where ever i choose the product (ie) from the Home page or else the product from the Category page. Everywhere the product has the same URLs without the main category. I am not that much expert in Magento and i am confused with your question.

Comment: Can someone answer this question. I am breaking my head with issue for so long days???

Comment: Finally found out a solution for this. In URL rewrite management itself all the URLs al\re generated only with the su-category. Reindexing code has been overwritten. Thanks to all.

Comment: how to export sku, category path(not id name) by mysql